# filterSelectedOptions in autocomplete Material UI Lab is not working with onChnage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-design

When I am using autocomplete for getting the selected dates, The selected options is not getting filtered. Hence i am able to select multiple instance of the same data. Although when i remove OnChange prop its giving the result but now i am not able to update the state.

```js
<Autocomplete
  multiple
  name="ClassSchedule"
  onChange={(event, value) => setDays(value)}
  ChipProps={{
    style: {
      backgroundColor: "#2EC5B6",
      borderRadius: "5px",
      color: "#fff",
      fontFamily: "Source Sans Pro",
    },
  }}
  id="tags-standard"
  options={[
    { title: "sunday" },
    { title: "monday" },
    { title: "tuesday" },
    { title: "wednesday" },
    { title: "thursday" },
    { title: "friday" },
    { title: "saturday" },
  ]}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <CssTextField
      {...params}
      style={{
        borderRadius: "10px",
        backgroundColor: "#F5FCFB",
        fontFamily: "Source Sans Pro",
      }}
      variant="outlined"
      id="custom-css-outlined-input"
    />
  )}
/>
```

Comment: you should reproduce your problem on codesandbox

Comment: [CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-star-fremb?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) 
This is the Link for Code Sandbox

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to `Autocomplete` [doc](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/):

> `value` - `any` - The value of the autocomplete. **The value must have reference equality with the option in order to be selected**. You can **customize the equality behavior with the `getOptionSelected` prop**.

> `getOptionSelected` - `func` - Used to **determine if an option is selected, considering the current value**. Uses strict equality by default.

So to know whether to exclude the selected value from the value in the list, you must implement `getOptionSelected` to check for the equality for exclusion, here is `.title`

```js
<Autocomplete
  ...
  getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.title === value.title}
  ...
/>
```

Below is the forked codesandbox

[image: Edit strange-perlman-6drzm]

Comment: With MUI v5, `isOptionEqualToValue` replaces `getOptionSelected`

Comment: What if you have more than one propriety in "getOptionLabel"? for example: getOptionLabel={(option) => `${option.id}  ${option.title}`}

Answer (score 1):

Your `onChange` function needs to be enhanced. You have to set the value array same as given in options array. Both array needs to match. You were getting details from `options--> Titles`. then You must set it by creating a similar array on `onChange`. like set `options--> Titles`

Try My working Sandbox example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/auto-complete-onchange-ejd9u)

Answer (score 1):

To give you more knowledge on what is happening: the main reason behind why putting your `onChange` handler is causing the `options` to be populated again with all the days, is because your component is **rerendered everytime you set the state for days** versus when you weren't setting the state for days. I've found that Material UI Autocomplete default checking works with an array stored in a state versus the hardcoded `options` you have

```
options={availableDays} //state based
```

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/so-react-material-ui-autocomplete-h2unq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks your answer works fine but setting a new state again is a overhead. The other answers did a pretty good job